# IOS 6.0 ignores my launch image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.5

I have been trying to get my app to work for the iPhone, after successfully getting it into the Google play store.  I am finding the process for iPhone to be worse than I even expected.

My problem duJour is that though I have launch images specified for every display, when I test in the IOS 6.0 simulator OR on an iPhone 5 I get the stupid default launch image and not the one I specified.

I assumed I had something mis-configured, but when I got the idea of trying it on the IOS 5.0 simulator it WORKED!  This is extremely frustrating.

I am using XCODE to do this 'visually'.  I am too much of a noob to be sure how to do this manually in the .plist and I cannot find any real documentation from apple about it.

I could sure use a link to some actual useful documentation, or even some help from someone who has experienced the same thing and found a solution.

Thanks!

BTW: I am using xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Make sure that you have cleaned all targets. Also it may help to delete the app from all simulators.

Comment: Wasnt clean: I was cleaning and cleaning with no effect.

Deleting the app did the trick.  Thanks so much for suggesting it!

If you had posted this as an 'answer' I would definitely mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check...

First, your naming conventions:

`Default.png` (320 x 480) for support of the original iPhone thru iPhone 3GS

`Default@2x.png` (640 x 960) for support of the iPhone 4 and 4S

`Default-568h@2x.png` (640 x 1136) for support of the iPhone 5

CaPiTaLiZaTiOn counts, so be careful.

Second, make sure each image is 72 dpi.

Third, do a Product->Clean from Xcode to make sure you've gotten rid of any old files lying around.  Also delete the app from the simulator and try running again.

Finally, try running on actual hardware.  Although the simulator is pretty good, there are a few differences in the way they work -- particular with how accommodating they are with images.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it wasn't the names or running clean: it was REMOVING the app from the simulators before running it again.

So this means that when testing with a sim OR an actual phone, if the app is there already it keeps the old launch image.  This probably makes sense to somebody at Apple.